# WPF SpellCheck Not Working via XML or Code-Behind

Tags: c#, wpf, spell-checking

I'm trying to distribute a WPF application (targeting .NET Framework 4.5.2) that has a Spell Check function enabled on a TextBox. After research I tried a couple of options:

via XML

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="5" x:Name="NotesTextBox" 
        SpellCheck.IsEnabled="true" xml:lang="en-US"
        ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 
        Margin="5" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
        AcceptsReturn="True" Height="225"/>
```

via code-behind

```
NotesTextBox.Language = System.Windows.Markup.XmlLanguage.GetLanguage("en-US");
NotesTextBox.SpellCheck.IsEnabled = true;
```

however neither of these methods are working. Words that are undoubtedly spelt incorrectly are not underlined.

I have read that installing the language pack (I'd need English) for .NET has fixed the issue for some people however I cannot find a pack for .NET 4.5.2 Windows 10.

Also, if I did get the language pack installed and the SpellCheck working, would I need to install the pack on every client machine that is going to use my software?

Comment: The code you show should work. So if it's not working, it's a configuration issue, and the marked duplicate describes how to address that. And yes, since the code depends on the language packs on the machine on which it's running, any machine where you want this to work will have to have the necessary language pack.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the additional Information provided here:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55169

> This version of the .NET Framework language pack installs side-by-side
>   with the .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 language pack and earlier versions,
>   but performs an in-place update for the Microsoft .NET Framework 4,
>   .NET Framework 4.5, .NET Framework 4.5.1, .NET Framework 4.5.2, .NET
>   Framework 4.6, .NET Framework 4.6.1 and .NET Framework 4.6.2 language
>   packs.

So the 4.7 language pack replaces the 4.5.2 language pack. so for Windows 10 install this.

Yes, you would need to install it on all client machines.

Comment: I'm now fully updated to .NET 4.7, and still no spell check working.. application is targeting .NET 4.7 too. When I try to run the link you provided the installer just says 4.7 is already installed so I'm assuming it has installed the language packs with it too?